# Unable to update, post and delete using django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am working on a simple blog project to learn the django rest framework. I am following the tutorial, however, there are certain things seem not to be working as expected.

Here I am trying to list, create, update, retrieve and destroy the objects. However, I am only able to list and create. The other three functionalities are not working as expected.

Below is my app :-

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    post = models.TextField(max_length = 100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from loginapp.models import *

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import generics
from loginapp.models import *
from loginapp.serializers import *
# Create your views here.

class BlogListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):   
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()   
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer


class BlogDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):    
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()   
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from loginapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^loginapp/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', views.BlogDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^loginapp/', views.BlogListCreate.as_view()),

]
```

Could you please help me out of this?

NOTE: There is no option available in the page to update/delete/retrieve.
Even if I pass the id value through url, it does not retrieve the expected record. Sorry, I am unable to attach the HTML page.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on how it is not working?

Comment: Hi, I am not seeing any option to update, retrieve or destroy any existing record. There is only button to POST when i hit the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginapp/` and if i hit url  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginapp/1` then the record with id = 1should be retrieved and should be available to get updated ir deleted. However, this is not happening.

Comment: is there any reason why you're using generics view? why not use `ModelViewSet` which gives you all the CRUD operations out of the box.

Comment: I did not reach until there in tutorial. I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want all CRUD functionality then Change your `views.py` to

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions

class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()   
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    # POST/PUT/PATCH will by default not be enabled in DRF ui 
    # unless  you are logged in so set permission classes to AllowAny or
    # empty(permission_classes = ()), Do not do it in Production   
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

and `urls.py` to

```
from loginapp.view import BlogViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'loginapp', BlogViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', router.urls),
]
```